# Как запустить написанную программу в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: Кликаю мышью на коде, и по идее должна быть кнопка Run,а ее нет.]

Кликаю мышью на коде, и по идее должна быть кнопка Run,а ее нет.Подскажите,что с этим делать.
Попутный вопрос:куда вводить данные при чтении с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Вот вам кнопочка Run]

Вот вам кнопочка Run. Нажимаете и в выпадающем меню нажимаете опять Run. Хоткей кажется F5 хотя могу ошибаться. Текст вводить в консольке которая откроется внизу окна при запуске программы.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c629121/v629121956/102fd/T4uv31RUKY8.jpg 
нажимаю run и выскакивает это

Comment: вот подробное описание https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html Скорее всего надо нажать на Edit Configuration и выбрать класс. Также возможно не запускается из-за ошибок в коде/конфигурации.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по подсветке красным System.out у вас не указана JDK. Откройте настройки проекта (File-Project Structure), на вкладке  Project укажите Project SDK(выделено на скриншоте)[image: Скриншот настроек проекта]

Comment: Так вроде все стоит 
https://pp.vk.me/c629121/v629121956/10372/OUR_3qFXRL8.jpg